# Bind jquery datatable from xml response

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a XML response from my webservice :

```
<TABLE>
<ROW>
<ID>1</ID>
<SEARCHKEY>XYZ</SEARCHKEY>
<SUBURB>XYZ</SUBURB>
<RATING>NA</RATING>
<DELIVERY>sss</DELIVERY>
<STATE>XYS</STATE>
<POSTCODE>1234</POSTCODE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ID>2</ID>
<SEARCHKEY>XYZ</SEARCHKEY>
<SUBURB>XYZ</SUBURB>
<RATING>NA</RATING>
<DELIVERY>sss</DELIVERY>
<STATE>XYS</STATE>
<POSTCODE>1234</POSTCODE>
</ROW>
</TABLE>
```

now i want to bind my `jquery` data-table using above XML. Right now i am converting this xml to datatable and then iterating each row like this :

```
                         <tbody>
                    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.dataGrid.Rows)
                    {
                        <tr >
                            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.dataGrid.Columns)
                            {  
                                <td >@row[col.ColumnName]</td> 
                            }
                        </tr> 
                    }
                 </tbody>
```

i didn't find my solution very appropriate.How i can bind this directly ? so the result will be like this : 
[image]

Should i first convert this `XML` to `json` ?? and then bind ?
please suggest me an efficient solution .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have converted my XML to array and then binded it to datatable.
Here is my solution, I hope it might help someone facing the same issue :)

```
$.ajax({
url: "/echo/xml/",
data: data,
type: "POST",
success: function (response) {

    var $events = $(response).find("ROW");
    $events.each(function (index, event) {
        var $event = $(event),
            addData = [];
        $event.children().each(function (i, child) {
            addData.push($(child).text());
        });

        thisTable.fnAddData(addData);
    });
}
});
```